# Do bonding and anti-bonding orbitals exist for ionic bonds?

Tags: bond, molecular-orbital-theory

Is there any concept of bonding and anti-bonding orbitals for ionic bonds, as there are in case of covalent bonds?

OR is it possible to break an ionic bond by pushing electrons into the antibonding orbitals?

I know that this question may sound stupid to some, but please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Ionic bonds are not about orbitals at all. Think, if you like, of a covalent bond in which the bonding orbital is skewed to the point of being totally centered around one atom.

Answer (score 1):

Bonding and antibonding orbitals in a homonuclear diatomic molecule  A-B should mix due to polarization to give rise to pair of atomic orbitals with delocalized tails  for an ionic heteronuclear diatomic molecule. Now suppose A more electronegative and is the rightful anion and B the cation. The tailed atomic orbital of A is the bonding orbital(ie. A:- B°+) and the one belonging to B is the antibonding (ie. A°+ B:-). See original paper on Coulson Fischer theory.